# Get the children propertie of a LayersControl object to add a new layer

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dash-leaflet

In a dash application with a Map component containing a LayersControl object initialized in a previous callback with different layers, I wan't to add another layer from a second callback but when I am passing the children property of the LayersControl I got a *cyclic object value* error.

Here is the way I declare my map component and the LayerControl object

```
dl.Map(
    id="maps",
    children = [dl.LayersControl(id = 'layers', children = [])],
    zoom=4, preferCanvas=True, zoomControl = False,
    style={
        'width': '1200px',
        'height': '720px'
    },
),
```

Then in a first callback I add several layers

```
@app.callback(
    Output('layers', 'children'),

)
my_first_callback() :

maps =  [
    dl.BaseLayer(
            dl.TileLayer(
                url = tileProvider.url.format(x="{x}", y="{y}", z="{z}", s="{s}", r=tileProvider.get("r", ""), **tileProvider),
                attribution="IGN"),
            name = 'fond de carte', checked = True
    ),
    dl.Overlay(dl.LayerGroup(layer1), name = 'layer1', checked = True),
    dl.Overlay(dl.LayerGroup(layer2), name = 'layer2', checked = True),
    dl.Overlay(dl.LayerGroup(layer3), name = 'layer3', checked = False),
]

return maps
```

Then I'm trying to update my LayersControl in a second callback

```
@app.callback(
    Output('layers', 'children'),
    State('layers', 'children'),
)
my_second_callback(layer_to_update) :
```

The app can't enter the callback cause line `State('layers','children')` rise *cyclic object value* error.
I was previously using only a LayerGroup in the map children property to add different layers. It was working perfectly but I wanted the possibility to hide/show layers and I don't understand why it is not working anymore.

Thanks to anyone who has a clue on this one !